# Need help to verify if my algebra is correct

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So here is the problem and my solution. I just want to know if it is correct or no. I tend to do frequent mistakes in simple algebraic computation..
$$cn\sum_{i=0}^{\lg n} 1/2^i = $$
$$= cn \frac{ 1-(1/2)^{lgn+1} }{1-(1/2)}$$
$$=cn  \frac{1-1/2n}{1/2}$$
$$=cn  (2 - 2/2n)$$
$$= cn  (2-1/n)$$
$$=2cn - cn/n$$
$$=2cn - c = c(2n - 1)$$

Did I do any mistakes? Thank you

Comment: Presumably, $\log n$ is $\log_2 n$, and you are assuming $\log_2 n$ is an integer?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's completely correct. It was important to have the log to the base 2.

Comment: why? $2^{logn+1} = 2n$ right?

Comment: Not unless the log is $log_2$.

Comment: oh, here we assume log base 2. Sorry it was unclear